# Error: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java

The code is meant to get te selected row of my tableview and set the status of the selected row to 3 (which in my database means reserved).

My code:

```
@FXML
private TableView tableView;

@FXML
public void handleReserveBtn(ActionEvent event) {
    TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableView.getSelectionModel();
    ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();

    try {
        Connection conn = DB.getInstance().getConn();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE items SET status = 3 WHERE "+selectedCells+" = ?");
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and the only error I get is: No value specified for parameter 1

pleas help me.

Comment: Did you consult any of the [online docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) before posting this question?

Comment: Because...you haven't provided a value for parameter 1. You have a WHERE clause with `= ?` in the prepared statement, but you haven't provided a value for that parameter via `setString(1, "value goes here")` (or `setInt` or any of the others).

Comment: That string concatenation with `selectedCells` looks...odd...too, given that it's some form of list. What is the code *meant* to do? As it says in the close-vote reason: *"Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Comment: The code is meant to get te selected row of my tableview and set the status of the selected row to 3 (which in my database means reserved).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set what the ? represents in the PreparedStatement.

Try this:

```
@FXML
private TableView tableView;

@FXML
public void handleReserveBtn(ActionEvent event) {
TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableView.getSelectionModel();
ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();

try {
    Connection conn = DB.getInstance().getConn();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE items SET status = 3 WHERE 
"+selectedCells+" = ?");
   //use PreparedStatement.set[datatype] and pass in the question mark index (starting from 1, not 0) along with your specified value for it
   stmt.setString(1, "value");//if the datatype for selectedCells is char or varchar
   stmt.setInt(1, value);//if the datatype for selectedCells is int
    stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());//replace this with a Logger
}
}
```